Planet Earth and the Polar Bear
In Planet Earth I, there was an episode where a polar bear woke up from its winter hibernate and started looking for food. Because of the global warming it can't reach the islands of the Seals and is forced to attack Sea Elephants, which eventually injure him severely in the leg and he dies.
Does anybody know the title or the index of that episode?

@Napoleon thanks for the edit! Don't you think that the [tag:documentary] should stay in the tags though? :)

We already know the films this is about, and we already know this film is a documentary. Genre tags are not to be used on each and every question about a film from that genre, only on questions that pertain to the intricacies of the genre itself, or identification questions looking for a film of that genre (though, you're not looking for a film, you already know the film).

Your description matches Episode 6 "Ice Worlds"

A female polar bear and her two cubs head off across the ice to look for food. As the sun melts the ice, a glimpse of the Earth's potential future reveals a male polar bear that is unable to find a firm footing anywhere and has to resort to swimming—which it cannot do indefinitely. Its desperate need to eat brings it to a colony of walrus. Although it attacks repeatedly, the herd is successful in evading it by returning to the sea. Wounded and unable to feed, the bear will not survive


The same female polar bear and her two cubs appear first in Episode 1 "From Pole to Pole", I just went on Netflix to confirm and took a screenshot. It might be worthwhile to add that detail to your answer, eventhough it is correct as it stands, considering the original question.

@GhotiandChips: Thanks for the suggestion. ☺
